# Compact space homotopy equivalent to a CW complex

Tags: compactness, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

Assume that $X$ is a **compact** Hausdorff space homotopy equivalent to some CW complex. Does it follow that it is homotopy equivalent to a compact CW complex?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but it points you to where compactness might fail (though I'm not sure it fails). Consider a homotopy equivalence $f:X\to Y$. The image of $f$ is compact, so restrict yourself to $f:X\to f(X)$. Let $g:Y\to X$ the homotopy inverse and restrict it to $g:f(X)\to X$. It is clear that $g\circ f\simeq id_X$ under the restriction, but if the original homotopy $f\circ g\simeq id_Y$ doesn't fix the subspace $f(X)$, then it doesn't automatically yield an equivalence $f\circ f\simeq id_{f(X)}$.

Comment: @Javi Also $f(X)$ doesn't have to be a CW complex, right?

Comment: You're right, $f(X)$ has to be a subcomplex of $Y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, the answer is no. The following facts are what I have pieced together from Mislin's article *Wall's Finiteness Obstruction*, which appears as chapter 26 of *The Handbook of Algebraic Topology*. In summary, there are indeed compact spaces with CW homotopy type which are not of the homotopy type of a *finite* CW complex.

A connected space $X$ is said to be *finitely dominated* if there is a finite complex $P$ and maps $\phi:X\rightarrow P$, $\psi:P\rightarrow X$ with $\psi\circ\phi\simeq id_X$.

> A finitely dominated space has the homotopy type of a CW complex of finite dimension.

However, examples produced by Lyra, *On a Conjecture in Homotopy Theory*, and later Wall, *Finiteness Conditions for CW-Complexes, I, II*, showed that there are finitely dominated spaces which are not of the homotopy type of a *finite* CW complex. Moreover Mather showd the remarkable fact that

> A connected space $X$ is finitely dominated if and only if $X\times S^1$ has the homotopy type of a finite CW complex.

It follows that $X\times S^1$ is compact, and therefore so is $X$, as it is the image of the continuous projection.

In general, given a finitely dominated space $X$ there is Wall's *finiteness obstruction*, which is a class $\sigma(X)\in\tilde K_0(\mathbb{Z}[\pi_1(X)])$ which vanishes if and only if $X$ is homotopy equivalent to a finite CW complex.

Comment: That is very unfortunate. But thank you for this quite complex example